# Chaining steps in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, jobs

I was reading the spring documentation for spring batch project, I want to know if there is an out of the box configuration to chain steps, it means the output of the first step be the input for the second one and so on. 
I'm not asking about step flows which one execute after other, is more about use the exit of the item processor of a step to be the input of the next one.

What I have in mind is use a normal step with reader, processor and in the writer create a flat file that could be reader by the second reader in the next step but this seems to be inefficiently as need to write objects that are in the jvm and restore them with the second reader.

If not sure if this is possible with spring normal config, or jsr does not work exactly as I want

Comment: Why would you need multiple steps for that? Use multiple `ItemProcessor`s and chain those using a `CompositeItemProcessor`.

Comment: Is exactly what I was looking and actually I was reading about it once at the same time you write your comment, consider add a explanation and write and answer so I can mark as the correct one, thanks. Pro Spring Batch chapter 8, pag 248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of multiple steps use multiple `ItemProcessor`s in a chain. You can chain them using a [`CompositeItemProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemProcessor.html).

EDIT :
I was reading about the spring batch strategies and I dont found any out of the box configuration in xml to chain the steps in a kind of pipeline, the best option that fit my needs is use ItemProcessorAdapter to run the different logic that I need in the steps and use [CompositeItemProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html) (6.21) to make a chain of them.